# Rails 3 passenger nginx application spawner server error on Synology NAS

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, synology

Question updated, please read **UPD2**.

I'm trying to deploy app through passenger nginx module on [DS710+](http://www.synology.com/us/products/ds710+/index.php) (ruby 1.9.2p0 installed). There is syntax error relative to has_and_belongs_to_many_association.rb file. Please look at the screenshot(deleted, question updated). I'm pretty sure the problem isn't in library file. App is running good via webrick. Could you please advise what to look for?

**UPD1**

ruby -v

```
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

gem list -d passenger

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

passenger (3.0.6)
Author: Phusion - http://www.phusion.nl/
Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/passenger
Homepage: http://www.modrails.com/
Installed at: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

Easy and robust Ruby web application deployment
```

**UPD2**

I've decided to reinstall everything. It solved previous problem but caused another one.
The error is: `The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Unexpected end-of-file detected.` Here is [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1677636/Screen%20shot%202011-04-20%20at%202.11.46%20PM.png).

New output:

ruby -v

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
```

gem list -d passenger

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

passenger (3.0.7)
Author: Phusion - http://www.phusion.nl/
Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/passenger
Homepage: http://www.modrails.com/
Installed at: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

Nginx error.log:

```
[ pid=5653 thr=32771 file=ext/common/Watchdog.cpp:128 time=2011-04-20 14:08:34.505 ]: waitpid() on Phusion Passenger helper agent return -1 with errno = ECHILD, falling back to kill polling
[ pid=5654 thr=49156 file=ext/common/Watchdog.cpp:128 time=2011-04-20 14:08:34.506 ]: waitpid() on Phusion Passenger logging agent return -1 with errno = ECHILD, falling back to kill polling
2011/04/20 14:12:33 [notice] 7614#0: signal process started
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you've got Ruby 1.9.2p0 installed, but your screenshot implies that Passenger is using 1.9.1 (which isn't supported by Rails); check your nginx passenger-configuration, specifically the `passenger_ruby` line.

Comment: I think it's just an old path after upgrading from 1.9.1. Because which ruby returns /usr/bin/ruby and in nginx.conf passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby; passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.6; It's really there.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ruby -v` and `gem list -d passenger`?

Comment: Sure. Updated question.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling passenger? All I can think of is that the native parts of passenger are probably compiled against Ruby 1.9.1 (implied by the path and your talk of upgrading) and that _might_ fix it.

Comment: I've already tried to recompile passenger. All my local gems including rails are under `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1`. App works fine using WEBrick. Isn't that confirms working with 1.9.2p0?

Comment: This isn't 1.9.1 issue. For compatibility reasons 1.9.2 installation will continue to use a path with 1.9.1: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/18/ruby-1-9.2-released/#label-6